# Can multiple JSON action types be run with the same trigger?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, json-formatting

I have added a button to a row in a list that can trigger a workflow. I would like it to set a field before running the flow. Do actions in JSON run synchronously? Can you run multiple actions?

This was my attempt but does not work.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Publish",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"6e4dc9d8-30ed-4123-ae8a-4b9ce24c2209\",\"headerText\":\"Copy To Enterprise\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Publish\"}",
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
      "PublishStatus": "Published"
    }
  },
  "style": {
    "background-color": "#008082",
    "color": "white",
    "border-radius": "0 15px"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the JSON schema: https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json,

`customRowAction` is an object which supports only one of the supported actions.

So, you cannot execute multiple actions on single button click.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. I'm new to JSON and the schema documentation doesn't mean much to me.

Comment: Does anyone know if multiple actions are still not supported as at August 2023?  It would be really helpful if we could do a `setValue ` (to set a column value immediately) and then an `executeFlow` (to run a flow after that).

Comment: Unfortunately, still not supported.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$FieldName]",
  "customRowAction":{
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
      "FieldInternalName_1": "FieldValue_1",
      "FieldInternalName_2": "FieldValue_2",
      "FieldInternalName_3": "=if([$Status] == 'Completed', 'yes', 'no')"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It will just updated the fields, it will not run the flow after updating field/column values.